# How can I automatically create a series of Pivotcharts based on a Pivottable in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, pivot-table, pivot-chart

**How can I automate create a series of Pivot Charts where the axis remains constant, yet the legend field and values field ititerates down the field list for each chart?**

---

**Situation:**

I have an excel workbook. In this workbook I have one sheet with a table. There are several other sheets that are pivotcharts based on the aforementioned table. For each of these pivotcharts I have been selecting the next item in turn in the pivottable field list to drag into both the "legend fields (series)" and the "values" areas. Then, I copy the pivotchart into a new worksheet, remove the previous field list item from the legend fields (series) and the values areas, then continue the aforementioned procedure. Neanwhile the axis fields (categories) area retains the same attribute across each of the pivotcharts. My aim is to create a series of pivotcharts on the pivottable to visualise some global health data for a report.

**Intuition:**

This procedure is routine. Since I estimate that I have around 150 field list items to work through I anticipate that it will be time saving to automate this process.

**Attempt at solving:**

I experimented with creating a macro of my going through one cycle of the aforementioned procedure. When I ran the macro I got an error indicating that I cannot name a chart with the same name as an existing chart. This was not my intention. Although I am unfamiliar with Visual Basic I attempted to copy the last paragraph of [code suggested by a forum poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466556/copy-a-worksheet-and-place-it-after-all-other-worksheets-and-rename-it-as-cell-r) who's advice I found after I googled for help. However, this seemed to cause additional issues and the macro again would not run.

I am unfamiliar with macros but I have heard they can automate processes. Can you recommend an efficient way forward one way or the other?

Thank you.

Comment: please post the code you have.

Comment: I have no code currently.